# Line break between GWT widgets

Tags: java, html, gwt

I'm trying to place two label/textbox pairs one on top of the other (like a login page).  Since my background is in HTML, I tried to hack a line break like this:

```
HTML html = new HTML("< br />");

panel.add(firstBox);
panel.add(html);
panel.add(secondBox);
```

It didn't drop the next label/textbox pair to a new line.  Any suggestions for either fixing this or a better overall way to position items on a panel in GWT?

Comment: You should definitely try the uibinder, it is by far the best way to do layouts. You can use an HTMLPanel as the parent widget and embed widgets with html entities. http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html . But if you really need to use the java for doing layout you should try using an HTMLPanel widget to add the br and your widgets.

Comment: Thanks the HTMLPanel worked! I must have missed that one in the widget gallery.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
panel.getElement().appendChild(DOM.createElement(BRElement.TAG));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
FlowPanel firstBox = new FlowPanel();
panel.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(100, Unit.PCT);
FlowPanel secondBox = new FlowPanel();
panel.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(100, Unit.PCT);
```